# google map like javascript library

Tags: dictionary

I want to display some custom data on 2D (but not with the world map) with google map fashion. Each data point has a coordinate on the 2D plan. Each data point has some attributes associated with it, users can click a point to display the associated info. Users can select the data based on the attributes. One example is the following webpage, but it is made of flash. Does anybody have a suggestion on what js library to use? Are there any example webpage using javascript?

app.nihmaps.org

Answer (score 3):

OpenLayers : Free Maps for the Web - http://openlayers.org/

Comment: It seems that OpenLayers use map services like WMS, etc. But I don't need to display a world map or a US map. I just need to display a set of points as on app.nihmaps.org, and I have these points in the format of a local file. Could you please point me an example that closely matches my purpose? Thanks!

Comment: while you would have to get your map into the appropriate format, I don't think that OpenLayers imposes any restriction on where your data comes from - see a simple "one tile" example at http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/single-tile.html

Answer (score 1):

When I was answering another [question about the use of css3 transforms for google maps behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504703/css3-zooming-on-mouse-cursor/15296290#15296290), I stumbled across a pretty slick jQuery plugin called [**Smooth Zoom Pan**](http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142) that does panning and zooming in google maps fashion ... and you can have any kind of background image + layers of information at desired zoom level ... however, if you want to use the plugin it will cost you a couple of bucks ( ... but seems to work good enough to be worth it)

But you can also just sneak a peek of the js code they use on their demo page and get an idea how to implement something similar in your own fashion =)