# CSS3, ZOOM + PAN (google maps style)

Tags: css, zooming, coordinate-systems, pan, coordinate-transformation

I need to ZOOM AND PAN a div element with CSS3 
with the ability to mix zoom and pan, 
 
so you could e.g. zoom-in, pan, zoom-in some more, pan, zoom-out etc.

ZOOMING has been SOLVED in this tread:
[CSS3 zooming on mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504703/css3-zooming-on-mouse-cursor)

with an absolutely BRILLIANT answer! here:
[CSS3 zooming on mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504703/css3-zooming-on-mouse-cursor/15296290#15296290)

Now the question is:
How to combine PANNING with the ZOOMING (from the answer above) ?

So far, I tried using jQuery UI draggable http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
like this:

```
<div id="graphics"> 
$("#graphics").draggable();
$("#graphics").draggable('enable');
```

but it "jumps" when I start dragging the image when it is zoomed-in.

I think a good answer to this could help quite a few people
as this is quite basic functionality and yet 
there is no solution for it on the web that I could find
after quite extensive search!

Comment: Solved it :) It was actually suprisingly simple!
#graphics must have: "position: relative" instead of "position: absolute"

Comment: You can answer and accept your questions so make sure to add your comment as the correct answer so the questions will be resolved/closed

Answer (score 1):

Solved it :) It was actually suprisingly simple! #graphics must have: "position: relative" instead of "position: absolute"